# I applied visitor visa for my parents and it got refused. I have attached the refusal letter.what can I do. Need help

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, standard-visitor-visas

[image]I am the financial source which  mentioned in the refusal letter . I provide my parents 50 pounds each month which reflects in my account.i am planning to provide my bank statement also.  Secondly , I am planning to attach letter from my father's brother and his family and his mother.
The land and house is in my name . So I am not sure whether I can attach that  . In there they have only car and gold of around 50 pawnas. So shall I do a valuation by chartered accountant about the car and gold.
Please suggest isbthis alright. I am the complete sponsor in uk as a daughter. I money in my parents account shows various cash amounts is that she pledged her some gold and put som money in her account . I am planning to attach the receipt of gold loan and statement of that bank. Need help

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139261/discussion-on-question-by-reshma-krajan-i-applied-visitor-visa-for-my-parents-an).